# Find a Regular expression in a database by a matching string in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a database in mongoDb, one of the fields in one of my collections is a Regular expression.

I need to match some string, and find which regexp fits to that string. However, for performance issues, I don´t want get every item in the collection and make a try and error for every regular expression in there.

Is there any way I can make a query to my collection sending the String I want to match with a specific collection's regular expression?

An example is I send in a query `1900-01-01` and it must give me the  object that has the regexp `^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`

Comment: I don't think you have much choice here but to iterate through (possibly) all objects in the collection until you find a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.col.find();
< { _id: ObjectId("6392dcac3bb5b657347cbd70"),
    regexField: BSONRegExp("^(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$", "") }
```

You can make use of [$regexMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) to check if the regex matches a given string.

```
> db.col.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: {
        "doesItMatch": {
          $regexMatch: {
            input: "1900-01-01", regex: "$regexField"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
< { _id: ObjectId("6392dcac3bb5b657347cbd70"),
    regexField: BSONRegExp("^(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$", ""),
    doesItMatch: true }
```

You can also use [$regexFind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/#exp._S_regexFind) and [$regexFindAll](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFindAll/#exp._S_regexFindAll)